# Cannot find sphinxbase.lib when compiling pocketsphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I checked out the latest version of CMUSphinx from github.I compiled sphinxbase successfully and while trying to compile pocketsphinx,I faced an error saying:

P.S: I used Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition to compile sphinxbase and VS2010 to compile pocketsphinx

"Cannot find sphinxbase.lib"

What may be the problem?

[image: Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx in the same parent folder:]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's trivial to figure path problems just by looking on compiler output, you can read the logs to see what happen. Sphinxbase path is hardcoded and if it does not match you see the problem like this.

Most likely you did not rename sphinxbase-5prealpha to just sphinxbase as suggested by instruction. Or you did not place sphinxbase and pocketsphinx sources to the same folder. You need to use VS 2013 for both projects as well.

Comment: I have placed both the sphinxbase and pocketsphinx folders in the same parent folder.And there are no path problems as well.I'm not able to compile pocketsphinx using VS 2013.It is opening only in VS 2010.What am I to do now?

Comment: I tried compiling pocketsphinx in VS 2013.It still says sphinxbase.lib cannot be opened ! I'm helpless !

Comment: You need to provide compilation log and the information about file layout in our system

Comment: The log is here : http://pastebin.com/wCfYWKA8 . The layout is like this.I have a base folder called sphinx which has two folders namely basesphinx and pocketsphinx in it.

Comment: it is better to provide me the screenshot of layout and contents of sphinxbase/bin folder. Are you sure you compiled sphinxbase release version and not sphinxbase debug version?

Comment: I have added the screenshots to mine question spec. I think I compiled the debug version.How do I compile the release version?

Comment: I compiled the release version successfully.But when I tried to execute this   bin/Release/pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic yes -hmm model/en-us/en-us -lm model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin -dict model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict ... It shows : 
INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13,
CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 83: Folder 'model/en-us/en-us' does not contain acoustic
model definition 'mdef'

Comment: You need to specify the path to the acoustic model folder properly, you can try with backslashes or absolute path to en-us folder.

Comment: The path was incorrect.Finally made it .Thanks a lot !